Why is apache ignoring my certbot cert and sending the domain request to a different cert?
I believe the two issues I'm having are related, but don't know where to begin. The first issue is that when a specific domain that resolves to my server is requested, its conf file in sites-enabled is ignored, as is 000-default.conf, instead the first conf next in alphabetical order is used and that site appears, but with the domain I requested in the browser bar.
This only happens with this one domain, which leads to the second problem. I have a multi-domain cert (CA) and all the domains in it show up as expected. I have an installed certbot cert for this other domain. When I use openssl with the domain name of this other domain, it shows the contents of the multi-domain cert. When I use an SSL checker I get the same results, with it noting that the domain name I entered is not included in the cert.
I notice that when I do apachectl -S prior to listing the *:443 and *:80 files it lists a virtual host with the server's IP address as the named server, and the first file it lists is not the 000-default (which IS listed as the first for *:80 and *:443) but the next one alphabetically.
THe problematic domain is halgrossman.com.
halgrossman.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName halgrossman.com
    ServerAlias www.halgrossman.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal/halgrossman/web
        <Directory /var/www/html/drupal/halgrossman/web>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

halgrossman.com-le-ssl.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName halgrossman.com
    ServerAlias www.halgrossman.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal/halgrossman/web
        <Directory /var/www/html/drupal/halgrossman/web>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/halgrossman.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/halgrossman.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

Output from openssl
openssl s_client -connect halgrossman.com:443 -servername halgrossman.com
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = theaccidentalcoder.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = theaccidentalcoder.com
   i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Sep  2 00:00:00 2024 GMT; NotAfter: Dec 21 23:59:59 2024 GMT
 1 s:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA384
   v:NotBefore: Nov  2 00:00:00 2018 GMT; NotAfter: Dec 31 23:59:59 2030 GMT
 2 s:C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Comodo CA Limited, CN = AAA Certificate Services
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA384
   v:NotBefore: Mar 12 00:00:00 2019 GMT; NotAfter: Dec 31 23:59:59 2028 GMT
 3 s:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Comodo CA Limited, CN = AAA Certificate Services
   i:C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Comodo CA Limited, CN = AAA Certificate Services
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA1
   v:NotBefore: Jan  1 00:00:00 2004 GMT; NotAfter: Dec 31 23:59:59 2028 GMT

theaccidentalcoder.com is the primary domain on a multi domain CA cert, which halgrossman.com is not part of.
Output from SSL Checker
halgrossman.com resolves to 45.56.118.187
    
Server Type: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
    
The certificate should be trusted by all major web browsers (all the correct intermediate certificates are installed).
    
The certificate was issued by Sectigo.    
    
The certificate will expire in 84 days. 
    
None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (halgrossman.com). You may receive an error when accessing this site in a web browser. Learn more about name mismatch errors.
    Common name: theaccidentalcoder.com
SANs: theaccidentalcoder.com, ascaatl.org, guildbuildersinc.com, musictohealby.com, souknook.com, thetouristlife.com
Valid from September 1, 2024 to December 21, 2024

Output from apache2ctl -S
45.56.118.187:443      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server guildbuildersinc.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/guildbuildersinc.com.conf:37)
         port 443 namevhost guildbuildersinc.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/guildbuildersinc.com.conf:37)
         port 443 namevhost musictohealby.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/musictohealby.com.conf:37)
         port 443 namevhost theaccidentalcoder.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/theaccidentalcoder.com.conf:23)
         port 443 namevhost thetouristlife.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/thetouristlife.com.conf:21)
*:443                  halgrossman.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/halgrossman.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server halgrossman.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/00-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost halgrossman.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/00-default.conf:1)
                 alias www.halgrossman.com
         port 80 namevhost default (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost guildbuildersinc.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/guildbuildersinc.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.guildbuildersinc.com
         port 80 namevhost halgrossman.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/halgrossman.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.halgrossman.com
         port 80 namevhost musictohealby.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/musictohealby.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.musictohealby.com
         port 80 namevhost theaccidentalcoder.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/theaccidentalcoder.com.conf:1)
                 alias www.theaccidentalcoder.com
         port 80 namevhost thetouristlife.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/thetouristlife.com.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"

Note that the domain list appearing first is listed for the IP, and does not include 000-default. The one it ** does ** list first, guildbuildersinc.com, is the first, alphabetically, after 000-default, and the site that appears when requesting https://halgrossman.com.

In this case, it turned out that the conf files for the domains in the multi domain cert had a 443 entry of:
<VirtualHost thedomainname:443>

instead of
<VirtualHost *:443>

So Apache was stopping at the first file encoded as such. When I fixed the first, alphabetically, it would stop at the next and return that site, and so on. Changing all of the .conf files to have the correct line fixed the issue.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@HackSaw the OP didn't format the code so it was interpreted as (bad) HTML and not displayed. All fixed now

Excellent. Sorry for the overly formal boilerplate, I was reviewing answers and didn't see the "Custom Comment" choice.
